# What is the difference if I don't use stdout=subprocess.PIPE in subprocess.Popen()?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I recently noted in Python the `subprocess.Popen()` has an argument:

```
stdout=None(default)
```

I also saw people using stdout=subprocess.PIPE.

What is the difference? Which one should I use?

Another question would be, why the wait() function can't wait until the process is really done sometimes? I used:

```
a = sp.Popen(....,shell=True)
a.wait()
a2 = sp.Popen(...,shell=True)
a2.wait()
```

sometimes the a2 command is executed before the command a is done.

Comment: in those other examples were people using the output from one as input in the next process?

Comment: how have you determined the subprocess is not really done? `process.wait()` won't return until the subprocess exited though if the subprocess has its own child processes then it might exit before all its child processes are complete

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`stdout=None` means, the `stdout`-handle from the process is directly inherited from the parent, in easier words it basically means, it gets printed to the console (same applies for `stderr`).

Then you have the option `stderr=STDOUT`, this redirects `stderr` to the `stdout`, which means the output of `stdout` and `stderr` are forwarded to the same file handle.

If you set `stdout=PIPE`, Python will redirect the data from the process to a new file handle, which can be accessed through `p.stdout` (`p` beeing a `Popen` object). You would use this to capture the output of the process, or for the case of `stdin` to send data (constantly) to `stdin`.
But mostly you want to use `p.communicate`, which allows you to send data to the process once (if you need to) and returns the complete `stderr` and `stdout` if the process is completed!

One more interesting fact, you can pass any `file-object` to `stdin/stderr/stdout`, e.g. also a file opened with `open` (the object has to provide a `fileno()` method).

To your `wait` problem. This should not be the case! As workaround you could use `p.poll()` to check if the process did exit! What is the return-value of the `wait` call?

[Furthermore, you should avoid `shell=True` especially if you pass user-input as first argument](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), this could be used by a malicious user to exploit your program! Also it launches a shell process which means additional overhead. Of course there is the 1% of cases where you actually need `shell=True`, I can't judge this with your minimalistic example.

Comment: you can't pass just any file object. It should be a file object with valid `.fileno()` e.g., `StringIO()` won't work.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I didn't want to write `file-like` because `StringIO` is `file-like`, any ideas how I can properly phrase it?

Comment: "any object with `.fileno()` method that returns an existing file descriptor" e.g., [`socket` works on my machine](https://gist.github.com/7454768)

Comment: Came upon this as I am also looking for the answers too. However I am not exactly understanding the answer - so is it alright to have `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` or not?

Comment: @yan: use `stdout=PIPE` **if and only if** you intend to read from the process' `stdout`. Is it clear?

Answer (score 8):

- `stdout=None` means that subprocess prints to whatever place your script prints
- `stdout=PIPE` means that subprocess' stdout is redirected to a pipe that you should read e.g., using `process.communicate()` to read all at once or using `process.stdout` object to read via a file/iterator interfaces