# Subprocess ignore all output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have CLI program that with parameters works automatically, however it still has a TUI (for example something written with [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library))) which can't be disabled. I am trying :

```
subprocess.check_call([executable, '-parameter'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

It disables most of the output, but still there's some left (parts that change). How to completly disable output from it? Thank you.

Comment: subprocess also takes input and output pipes, you will want to give it an output pipe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269575/how-to-hide-output-of-subprocess-in-python-2-7)

Comment: isn't the output pipe already set as `subprocess.DEVNULL`?

Comment: [nope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19961290/7540911)   [`With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

Comment: okay. Thank you for explaination. BTW `stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` worked.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to redirect both stdout AND stderr.

```
subprocess.check_call([executable, '-parameter'], 
    stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
)
```